# R plotly multiple plots only show last figure

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to make an interactive graphs based on user input. However I'm struggle to make more than one graphs using R plotly. Suppose I have following data and codes,

```
dput(norwd5)
structure(list(LENGTH_OF_STAY = c(57L, 28L, 15L, 28L, 14L, 49L, 
15L, 22L, 17L, 81L, 34L, 24L, 31L, 38L, 33L, 22L, 21L, 49L, 188L, 
21L, 21L, 36L, 24L, 23L, 48L, 54L, 42L, 62L, 13L, 139L, 29L, 
49L, 15L, 7L, 43L, 28L, 31L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 33L, 30L, 127L, 22L, 
22L, 15L, 28L, 26L, 15L, 31L, 22L, 89L, 28L, 60L, 54L, 37L, 20L, 
135L, 155L, 51L, 15L, 8L, 38L, 16L, 16L, 22L, 30L, 14L, 16L, 
18L, 14L, 272L, 25L, 22L, 18L, 21L, 188L, 264L, 34L, 34L, 136L, 
23L, 142L, 25L, 32L, 58L, 163L, 16L, 35L, 23L, 50L, 71L, 10L, 
19L, 22L, 24L, 45L, 29L, 15L, 82L), PRE_OPERATIVE_LOS = c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 179L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 110L, 63L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 
5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 171L, 
5L, 4L, 116L, 6L, 47L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 60L, 1L, 3L, 20L, 31L, 49L, 
9L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 35L, 7L, 4L, 9L), POST_OPERATIVE_LOS = c(55L, 
26L, 12L, 27L, 11L, 43L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 79L, 23L, 22L, 25L, 35L, 
27L, 19L, 16L, 46L, 9L, 19L, 16L, 33L, 20L, 21L, 43L, 48L, 40L, 
58L, 11L, 133L, 26L, 47L, 13L, 1L, 37L, 27L, 27L, 17L, 17L, 21L, 
33L, 26L, 121L, 20L, 18L, 11L, 21L, 22L, 11L, 25L, 20L, 85L, 
25L, 57L, 52L, 31L, 16L, 25L, 92L, 45L, 11L, 1L, 33L, 15L, 10L, 
21L, 26L, 12L, 10L, 15L, 12L, 264L, 23L, 20L, 14L, 18L, 182L, 
93L, 29L, 30L, 20L, 17L, 95L, 22L, 25L, 55L, 103L, 15L, 32L, 
3L, 19L, 22L, 1L, 11L, 19L, 20L, 10L, 22L, 11L, 73L), digoxin_any = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0:No", "1.Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000012f36b61ef0>)

num <- c('PRE_OPERATIVE_LOS','POST_OPERATIVE_LOS')
plist <- scan(text=num,what = "",quiet = T)
groups <- 'digoxin_any'
bygrp <- scan(text=groups,what="",quiet=T)
norwd5[, (bygrp) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = bygrp]

plotList = list()
for(i in length(plist)){
gplot <- ggplot(norwd5,aes_string(x=plist[i],group=bygrp,color=bygrp))+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),position = "dodge")+geom_density(alpha=.5) +theme(legend.position = "left")
  plotList[[i]] <- plotly_build(gplot)
}

for(i in length(plist)){
print(plotList[[i]])
}
```

The goal is to show both graphs for PRE_OPERATIVE_LOS and POST_OPERATIVE_LOS. However, the codes above only show histogram for POST_OPERATIVE_LOS.

I checked maybe subplot is the way to go but how to make subplot work in a loop? Any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: Try with `for (i in seq_along(plist))` or `for (i in 1:length(plist)` to loop over all elements of plist instead of just the last element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seq_along does work well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your first loop and calling each subplot won't make both appear at the same time.

First-- the issue with your first `for` call- when you wrote

```
for(i in length(plist))
```

You wrote `for i in 2` or `i == 2`, meaning that you never looped. If you modify it to a range of values, now it's written: `for i in 1 to 2`.

```
for(i in 1:length(plist))
```

So you're aware, if you had written `for(i in plist)` it would have done both loops, but instead of a value, `i` would be the strings.

Okay, so now there are two graphs. From the `plotly` library, you can use the function `subplot`. You will want to turn the legend off for one of them, though.

```
subplot(plotList[[1]],
    style(plotList[[2]], showlegend = FALSE))
```

[image]

If you wanted the outline color, that's more than okay! However, if you wanted to bars to be *filled*, you need to assign `fill` instead of `color`.

If you change `color = bygrp` to `fill = bygrp`, this is how this would change:

[image]

If you leave the `color` assignment and *add* `fill = bygrp` (so you have both), this is how this would change:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanations! Just curious, what's your package versions?   I'm running plotly_4.9.2.1 on R 4.01 but  l can't get multiple graphs work in a loop since I'm using this within shiny app, there is no way to list subplot by each of them without using any sort of loop, however, I accept your thoughtful answer for my initial question!

Comment: I've R 4.1.1 (Intel Mac version) & `plotly` version 4.10.0. It looks like `plotly` has had a lot of changes. You should be able to use `crosstalk` with the version you have. With the package `crosstalk` you can do all sorts of things. For example, if you couldn't get `subplot` to work, you could use `combineWidgets(plotList[[1]], plotList[[2]], nrow = 1)`. I'm not sure what you mean regarding the loop and `shiny`, though. So whatever your issue is, there may not be resolved with `crosstalk` either. (Although, that's sort of its purpose.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information! I'll check crosstalk out...for loop part, I mean```for(i in 1: length(plist)){ print(plotList[[i]]) } ``` only one plot was shown. Since i(how many graphs) will be defined by UI input within Shiny app, I can't explicitly list subplots in the code.